# Change value with upper and lower limit

Tags: python, replace, range, rename

I have one dataset with several column: data-pioggia-name.....

I would like to rename values, within of the column pioggia.
I would like:

- values<0 = 0
- values>400 = 0

I tried with:

```
data.loc[data.pioggia < 0]= "0"
```

But I have one problem with values > 400 = 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap, I am guessing your DataFrame is called `data` and `pioggia` is the name of the column that serves as filter for the values to be changed.

If so, then the following code should do:

`data['pioggia'].loc[(data['pioggia'] < 0) | (data['pioggia'] > 400)] = 0`

Note that when you write `"0"` you are entering a string whose only character is `0`, not a number.

Which is the error that you're facing for values > 400, anyway?

Comment: with your code sometime I have this error: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

Comment: Can you share the code you are running? P.S. Note that I was wrong with the logical operator: you have to use "or" and not "and".

Comment: I wrote one answer below, because I have some problem within comment.

Answer (score 0):

I share my code with some corrections:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv('name_dataset', sep=';')
data.info ()

data['pioggia']=data['pioggia'].fillna(0) #within dataset there is NAN
data['pioggia']=data['pioggia'].astype(int) #change value in int
data['pioggia'].loc[data.pioggia < 0]= 0 #change value<0 =0
data['pioggia'].loc[data.pioggia > 400]= 0 #change value>400 =0

# in my case I wanted to create the sum of the values, it is similar pivot table
x1_1=data.groupby('variable')[['pioggia']].sum()
```

or there is other solution, to get data inside interval. Getting 0<value<400

```
start=0
end=400
data['pioggia']=data['pioggia'].astype(int)
data.pioggia=(data['pioggia']>start)&(data['pioggia']<=end)
```